# Simple Java framework/tool for web-based DB table access?

Tags: java, database, spring-roo

I'm looking for a web-based Java tool (preferably one that will run in both Weblogic and JBoss) that will allow controlled access to a particular database. I need to allow non-technical users to insert, update, and delete rows in a particular Oracle DB table. The rows will be of varying data type (some dates, some numbers). Ability to add dropdowns with specific values would be nice.

Also nice, but not necessary (since we can always use a reverse proxy) would be the ability to control read/write access using LDAP/AD groups.

Another developer on my team suggested Spring/Roo, but that may be too heavyweight for what we're looking to do. There's got to be something simpler out there... Oracle Apex is another option, if we get desperate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Roo is absolutely not an overkill for this task in my opinion. It actually supports database reverse engineering, so you can explicitly specify which tables you want to have a CRUD view for.

You will need a really simple script, something like this:

```
project --topLevelPackage org.whatever --projectName crud --java 6
persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database ORACLE
```

--> you will need to acquire `ojdbc*.jar` because it's not available from Maven

--> also you will need to adjust `database.properties` to suit your needs

```
database reverse engineer --schema my --includeTables "Table1 .." --package ~.domain 
controller all --package ~.web
logging setup --level DEBUG --> OPTIONAL
security setup --> OPTIONAL
exit
```

That's it, you can run your application.

Answer (score 6):

Grails is a great cheap way to build a CRUD app like you're describing, and it integrates cleanly with Java applications.  You can probably build your first prototype app in an hour or two to get a feel for it.  Here's a decent starter tutorial: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails01158/

Answer (score 1):

Just write a simple web application with a few JSP files if that is all that you need to do.  You can package them into a WAR file and deploy them easily to either JBoss or Weblogic.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is a java-based Web Framework that gives you automatic Create/Retrieve/Update/Delete (CRUD) screens. There are a huge number of frameworks available, each with different strengths and weaknesses. You don't give enough information to make a reasonable suggestion of which would be best, so I would recommend that you play around with different frameworks until you find the one best suited to your needs.

Spring Roo is one way to try out different frameworks, but I find that it has a lot of typing overhead to build the model you want. If you recorded a script you could perhaps replay it with different frameworks selected for generation, but that may be too complicated.

I would recommend you check out AppFuse, which is a meta-framework that allows you to play with different frameworks easily. See [AppFuse QuickStart](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart) for information on getting started.

As for controlling access to the tables using LDAP, there are many possibilities available. Java provides direct control as [shown here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html) . Another option that many use is [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/).

Comment: Roo provides reverse engineering so you don't have to type at all to create your entities